# any idea why this php array won't work properly

Tags: php, arrays, telegram-bot

i'm using telegram bot api to make a bot for my business purposes, in my project i need to store data sent by bot into a file and then use the data, my problem is i can't query the array given by bot
below is my array and for example let's say i want to access message_id

in my script to access message_id i wrote this code:

```
$my_array = file_get_content('log');
echo $my_array['result']['message_id']
```

but it won't work.

```
Array
(
    [ok] => 1
    [result] => Array
        (
            [message_id] => 599
            [from] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 224181375
                    [first_name] => boofeh
                    [username] => boofehbot
                )

            [chat] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 50408323
                    [first_name] => MOƎIN
                    [username] => imoein1
                    [type] => private
                )

            [date] => 1466751591
            [text] => اکنون سفارش خود را ارسال کنید
        )

)
```

Comment: check `echo "<pre/>";print_r($my_array);` it will output some different array for-sure what you shown to us. you can use `var_dump($my_array);` also

Comment: also `echo $my_array['result']['message_id']` here  `;` missed. May be TYPO. if not add it and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you [serializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array before writing it to the file?
 And [unserializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it after reading it from file?

Here is how you can serialize and unserialize the array like this,

```
$serialized_string = serialize($array);
```

This is how you serilize the array.

To unserialize it,

```
$serialized_string = file_get_contents('log');
$array = unserialize($serialized_string);
print_r($array);
```

Now you can access you data in array like,

echo $my_array['result']['message_id'];

> **serialize()** generates a storable representation of a value
>
> **unserialize()** takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: it sucks when people not responding. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, That's true!